# How to improve deep neural network to work with bigger input image?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, image-recognition

I'm trying to use deep neural network to detect road signs on images (based on [the tflearn example](https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/blob/master/examples/images/convnet_cifar10.py)):

```
dataset_file = [path_to_dataset_file]
X, Y = image_preloader(dataset_file, image_shape=(32, 32), mode='file',
                       categorical_labels=True, normalize=True)
X, Y = shuffle(X, Y)

network = input_data(shape=[None, 32, 32, 3])
network = conv_2d(network, 32, 3, activation='relu')
network = max_pool_2d(network, 2)
network = conv_2d(network, 64, 3, activation='relu')
network = conv_2d(network, 64, 3, activation='relu')
network = fully_connected(network, 512, activation='relu')
network = dropout(network, 0.5)
network = fully_connected(network, 2, activation='softmax')
network = regression(network)

model = tflearn.DNN(network, tensorboard_verbose=0)
model.fit(X, Y, n_epoch=1000, show_metric=True)
```

It works really nice with small images (32 x 32px), but I would like to improve my network to work with bigger images (500 x 500px or bigger if possible) with road signs in the background, in the corner, etc. Attempt to run this code with shape=[None, 500, 500, 3] killed my computer :)

I'm thinking about this way (pseudo-code):

```
SIZE_GOOD_ENOUGH = 32

def try_detect(image):
    if image_too_small(image):  # image is too small when width
        return FALSE            # or height < SIZE_GOOD_ENOUGH
    resized_image = image.resize_to(SIZE_GOOD_ENOUGH, SIZE_GOOD_ENOUGH)
    result = detect_with_DNN(resized_image)  # returns TRUE if detected
    if result:
        return TRUE
    smaller_images_list = cut_into_pieces(image)  # list of smaller images
    for smaller_image in smaller_images_list:
        result = try_detect(smaller_image)  # recursion
        if result:
            return TRUE
    return FALSE
```

...or something like that, but still I would like have bigger SIZE_GOOD_ENOUGH, becouse some resized road signs are difficult to recognize even for me. Is there any way to improve my network to work better with (for example) 200 x 200px images? Better for me means "do not kill my GPU" and still results with accuracy > 0.9. Maybe my conv_2d/max_pool_2d are not well selected? I would be gratefull for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reducing GPU memory usage, you can reduce more the spatial size of feature maps in the beginning of the network. For training a larger network, it's necessary to have a GPU of 4G memory or more, or several GPUs.

Another point, I suppose that the examples of 32x32 are centered on road signs while images 500x500 are road scenes, not just signs. In this case, you'd better do something like object detection.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I found this link: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/object_detection using your advice and it looks like easy solution to all of my problems! :)